# 3 digit hexadecimal generator for Access Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, random, hex

I am trying to figure out how to create a hexadecimal generator that always spits out 3 digits in C# and sends it to my access database. Here is the code that I found an example of on here and changed a little bit, but the generator sometimes only gives me 2 digits. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

```
        var r = new Random();
        int A = r.Next(100, 500);
        string hexValue1 = A.ToString("X");
        MessageBox.Show(hexValue1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in

[The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier)

> The precision specifier indicates the minimum number of digits desired in the resulting string. If required, the number is padded with zeros to its left to produce the number of digits given by the precision specifier.

So you can simply use

```
string hexValue1 = A.ToString("X3");
```

to always give you three digits (provided that A <= 0xFFF)..

Answer (score 1):

The minimum possible value for a 3 digit hex value would be `0x100` (256 decimal) and the maximum value would be `0xFFF` (4095 decimal). So in order to generate this string you need to use something like:

```
var r = new Random();
int A = r.Next(256, 4096); //Using the exclusive maximum (required max + 1)
string hexValue1 = A.ToString("X");
MessageBox.Show(hexValue1);
```